# Dlang : how to enforce an interface on a template function

Tags: d

I've been googling for two hours looking for this with no luck.

If I have a template function and I want to enforce an interface on the template type, how do I do so?

ex.

```
void doStuff(T)(bool param) /*if T is a Throwable*/ {
    // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using a template constraint:

```
void doStuff(T)(bool param) if(is(T : Throwable)) { }
```

`is` expressions can be quite complex, so I suggest having a read through [this](https://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#IsExpression).

Comment: There we go. That's a bit more elegant than I expected.

Comment: There's a actually a prettier way to do it, rather than the `is` keyword. `void doStuff(T : Throwable)(bool param) { }`

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it, rather than using the `is` keyword like mitch_'s answer is this.

```
void doStuff(T : Throwable)(bool param) { }
```

See: https://dlang.org/spec/template.html#TemplateTypeParameterSpecialization